# How to delete an hierarchy tree in SQL

Tags: sql, hierarchy

I have built an hierarchy and I'm able to insert, move, but I having problems with deleting.
I created this stored procedure to delete an Hierarchy Tree.

I call the procedure using exec **[tag].[usp_TagDeleteHierarchyTree] 45** but the records are being displayed instead of being deleted.

**Sample data**

[image]

In the **messages** I get:

[image]

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [tag].[usp_TagDeleteHierarchyTree]
     @TagId float
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ParentNode hierarchyid

    Begin Try
        Begin Transaction
            -- Parent node
            Select  @ParentNode = [Node] From [tag].[Process] Where [Tag_Id] = @TagId
            -- Delete records
            Delete From [tag].[Process] Where [Node].IsDescendantOf(@ParentNode) = 1
        Commit Transaction
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        Rollback Transaction
    
        Return ERROR_MESSAGE()
    End Catch
END
```

I can't figure out what is wrong, any idea?

Regards
Elio Fernandes

Comment: You can use a cascading delete foreign key constraint rather than a trigger.  Much simpler.

Comment: Please, provide sample data, desired output and tour current output in text format. We cannot guess what is wrong with your code because there's no any input or output data for it

Comment: Although I think I don't need to use cascading delete because this table is used only for tagging I will try to use a cascading delete foreign key constraint. Thanks Gordon. I also updated the post with Sample Data and Messages in text format.

Comment: maybe IsDescendantOf is being affected by the delete statement?